# Center image above text

Tags: html, css

I want to display several images next to each other and each image has a date below it. The date is wider than the image and I would like to center the image on top of the date. Here's a code snippet

```
<div style="float:left">
      <div class="newsfeed_photo">
      <a href="...">
      <img alt="Small" class="photo_thumb_frame" src="..." />
      </a></div>
      <div class="newsfeed_date">
      (08/17/11 03:29pm)
      </div>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
      <div class="newsfeed_photo">
      <a href="...">
      <img alt="Small" class="photo_thumb_frame" src="..." />
      </a></div>
      <div class="newsfeed_date">
      (08/22/11 02:16pm)
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you should just be able to use `text-align: center`:

http://jsfiddle.net/rahjU/

Comment: Yep, should have seen that, thanks. In case anyone is wondering, here's the change `<div style="float:left; text-align:center">`.

Answer (score -1):

To shift your image **Before** other content (visually)

```
.img {
  order: -1;
}
```

[W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common)